# Excel: Find and Replace External Reference Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find-replace

**The true problem I'm trying to solve:**

- I've pasted text including formulas from one Excel workbook to another, but I don't want to reference the old workbook in the formulas

The question I'm asking:

- How can I find and replace (or similar results) references to an old workbook, where I want formula to instead reference (identically named) internal data table? I want to replace the values within a formula, but my best guess is that Excel is having a problem with some kind of special character

## Sample:

The following is formatted as a data table named "Data" in "MyOldWorkbook.xlsx" and "MyCurrentWorkbook.xlsx"

| ColRowNum | ColAmt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 5 |

- The original/desired formula: `=COUNTIFS(Data[ColAmt],"<=10")`
- The unwanted formula when pasted: `=COUNTIFS('MyOldWorkbook.xlsx'!Data[ColAmt],"<=10")`

**Notes:**

- The sample is overly simplistic. The easiest thing to do is manually just deleted out the unwanted text, but I'm looking for the systematic solution.
- I feel like I'm missing some "escape" character command/grep thing/something in the find & replace dialogue.

## Fails

- If I try to put into the Find and Replace dialogue box(es)  Find: 'MyOldWorkbook.xlsx'! and replace with "" (actually blank), I get an error.
- If I try to shorten it (remove the !) I get an error about how excel has broken formulas (true) and refuses to find/replace for me
- Can't break the external links, since that converts my formulas (formula, in this simple example) to numbers

**UPDATE** *I've encountered this issue before and didn't have a solution other than manually fixing the text. When I was replicating the problem to a colleague, the above find-and-replace method actually worked. I don't think this has ever worked for me before. Does anyone have any ideas????*

## Sort of not-a-terrible-Solution: Use a Formula

As I'm posting this, stackoverflow tried to see if my question was answered before and it got me thinking which got to a solution that isn't horrendous, though I was hoping to use the GUI find/replace feature:
A1 (formula): `=COUNTIFS(Data[ColAmt],"<=10")`
B1 (text): 'MyOldWorkbook.xlsx'!

1. Use this formula in C1 `=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),B1,"")`
2. Copy and paste-vales from C1 into D1
3. Done

## Terrible (but relatively functional) solution: Paste As Text etc.

1. Format formula cell as TEXT (or paste formula in a cell formatted as text)
2. Find/Replace "=" with "" to remove Excel thinking it's a formula (or otherwise remove "=")
3. Find/Replace "'MyOldWorkbook.xlsx'!" with ""
4. stitch back formula in some way and copy text back to original formula cell

Comment: Find/Replace _should _ work, I've used that myself many times in this situation.

Comment: Another option is Edit Links, Change Source, and select the current workbook

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically remove references to different workbooks in Excel formulas using either a macro or VBA script.

You can loop through all of the cells in a worksheet and modify the formulas to remove any references to external workbooks.  I have created an example below:

```
Sub remove_external_references()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'Change to the desired worksheet

    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
        If cell.HasFormula Then
            cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, "[", "")
            cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, "]", "")
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

This script uses the Replace function to remove any square bracket characters "[" and "]" from the formula, which are typically used to indicate a reference to an external workbook.

You could of course change it anyway you want to, for example: `cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, "'MyOldWorkbook.xlsx'!", "")`

Additionally, you can use the Workbook.LinkSources property to get the list of external links for a workbook, and use the Workbook.ChangeLink method to update the references.